# Are there undocumented FB.init options?

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

**[The docs for `FB.init`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/)** list the following options:

- `appId`
- `cookie`
- `logging`
- `status`
- `xfbml`
- `channelUrl`
- `authResponse`
- `frictionlessRequests`
- `hideFlashCallback`

However, I have seen several FaceBook webapps useing additional options, including (but probably not limited to)

- `useCachedDialogs`
- `oauth`
- `secret` (*for the appSecret - this is a bad idea right?*)

Are these standard options for `FB.init`? If so, where are they documented, if at all?

If not, are these custom options?  and what would the benefit would be of doing something like this.

Comment: `oauth` is (or was) documented. It was necessary to use oauth in js sdk. `useCachedDialogs` is for mobile apps. From [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/web/build/) By default, dialogs will be pre-cached for performance reasons. If you would like to disable that for debugging reasons, set the "useCachedDialogs" flag to "false" in init().

Comment: `Secret` shouldnt be visible on client side, I dont think facebook will have ever said to include this at client side.

Comment: Do you think I should report `oauth` & `useCachedDialogs`'s ommission as a documentation bug?  

re: `Secret`: agreed, I was quite surprised to find it on a live FB app.

Comment: If you want to drop that comment into an answer, I'll give you an upvote, and, if no other useful info comes in after a while I give you the checkmark as well ;-)

Comment: `oauth` is no longer required now. And `useCachedDialogues` is for mobile apps. Means any website using those 'extra' options are either outdated or not a web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Copy n Paste from comments*

`oauth` is (or was) documented. It was necessary to use `oauth` in js sdk. `useCachedDialogs` is for mobile apps. From [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/web/build/)

> By default, dialogs will be pre-cached for performance reasons. If you
>   would like to disable that for debugging reasons, set the
>   "useCachedDialogs" flag to "false" in init().

`Secret` shouldnt be visible on client side, I dont think facebook will have ever said to include this at client side